How to Authorize Requests to a GraphQL API with Keycloak in .NET Aspire Project?
I'm working on a .NET Aspire project where I've integrated Keycloak as the Identity Provider (IDP). I followed the setup instructions from this workshop.
Now, I need to authorize requests to my GraphQL API from my web project. Additionally, I want to allow users to make their own requests to the GraphQL API, but I need a convenient and secure way to handle authorization for both these methods.
What would be the best approach to achieve this? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
